# Concurrent hash table/hash set in C++ without 'thread management'?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, libraries, hashset

I need to fill a hash set from an array of non-unique elements quickly in C++ - so I want to use a concurrent hash set and multiple threads insert()ing into it.

However, I've noticed that some/many/all concurrent data structure libraries available for C++ involve some sort of thread management mechanism, which you have to use in order to avail yourself of their concurrent data structures. (I'm only 90% sure of what I'm saying since I have not dug into the code of TBB or LibCDS etc.

So, my question is: Which libraries offering concurrent hash maps / hash sets do not require you to use their thread management, but just (say) have one thread create the structure, than any number of threads perform insert/find/delete operations?

Comment: If you want to avoid the fine-grained locking then you need a thread-unsafe version of a hashmap class and do coarse-grained locking yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your own locking (if that is what you mean by "thread management") when using concurrent containers from Intel Thread Building Blocks. Read up on [concurrent_hash_map](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/tbb_userguide/concurrent_hash_map.htm).